# Problem with comparing Varchar in sqlserver. Using = is not working

Tags: sql-server

I am writting a trigger in sql server on updating the inventory of some item. I want to update the inventory according to the purchased order status. Related code is like this:

```
declare @status varchar(50)
select @iID = i.itemID, @oID = i.orderID FROM inserted i;
select @status = orderPurchase.orderStatus FROM orderPurchase WHERE orderPurchase.orderID = @oID

BEGIN
    IF @status = 'C' 
        update item SET inventory = @result1 WHERE itemID = @iID;
    ELSE 
        update item SET inventory = @result2 WHERE itemID = @iID;
END
```

However, the result shows it always increases the inventory no matter the order status is 'C' or 'R' which means returned.

Can you help with this problem? Thnaks in advance.

Comment: @HuiminMaiao please share your error.

Comment: One problem (which may or may not have occurred already), is that the virtual `inserted` table may contain more than one row. The `select @iID = i.itemID, @oID = i.orderID FROM inserted i` statement will then assign values from a random row in the inserted table. You need to rewrite your trigger with that in mind.

Comment: Where are `@result1` and `@result2`coming from?

Comment: Please share the table for this trigger. Is this from orderPurchase or something else?

Comment: Post ALL the trigger code, not just a portion. And you have made a very common mistake - assuming the statement that fired the trigger affected a single row. A statement can affect zero (yes - zero), 1, or many rows. Don't assume any number and write your code to work correctly in all situations.

Comment: And if you want to assign the result of a query to a scalar value (like @status), then use SET rather than SELECT. Why? If your query returns multiple rows, a SET statement will generate an error and you will be able to find and fix this error. A SELECT statement will assign a value from one of the rows but you cannot know which one. There are other differences as well.

Comment: In addition to TT's and Jen R's response, you should realize, that if inserted is empty, or if there is no match for the orderID, then @status will keeps its default value, which is NULL. In that situation, the "ELSE" branch will always be executed. You should add handling for no matches.